# Go code not working

Tags: go, visual-studio-code

I am trying out following sample snippet to run on my vscode editor

below is a snippen which i think is problematic. Vscode does point to some error but maybe I am missing that.

> app.go

```
package main

import {
    "database/sql"
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "github.com/gorilla/mux"
    _ "github.com/lib/pq"
}

type App struct {
    Router *mux.Router
    DB *sql.DB
}
//init and other functions here
```

> model.go

```
package main

type product struct {
   ID    int     `json:"id"`
   Name  string  `json:"name"`
   Price float64 `json:"price"`
}
//some code below
```

When I try to run vscode debugger with above given settings, it gives me below errors:

```
can't load package: package .: 
app.go:3:8: expected 'STRING', found '{'
app.go:4:2: expected ';', found 'STRING' "database/sql"
exit status 1
Process exiting with code: 1
```

I am not able to debug as this is very vague to me and I have tried looking for it on other forums. Would be greatful if someone can help with what to do with the above error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The import block is supposed to be surrounded in parentheses, not braces.

```
import (
    "database/sql"
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "github.com/gorilla/mux"
    _ "github.com/lib/pq"
)
```